# Touchscreen keyboard appears even when turned off

Tags: settings, touchscreen

I never want to use a touchscreen keyboard, but I do want to use my touchscreen as a mouse.

In settings, under universal access and typing, I've turned off the on-screen keyboard.

But whether the toggle switch is off or on, when I touch the screen, the keyboard blocks half the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by using a Gnome Extension called [Block Caribou](https://github.com/lxylxy123456/cariboublocker)

At least works on my Ubuntu 20.10 with Gnome Version 3.38.3

Comment: Thanks.  I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and have that extension turned on, but the keyboard still keeps popping up.

Comment: Where are you looking to enable/disable the extension? I only ask as if you are using the extensions.gnome.org and browser extension I have had issues getting any extensions to work via that method in later Ubuntu releases. But I found if I use the `Extensions` app icon or the `Extensions` section in the `gnome-tweaks` app I can get the extensions to enable/disable and work as expected.